# JavaScript Find average from user input

Tags: javascript, average

I am having trouble calculating the mpgTotal. This should add together all of the mpgTankful and divide them by how many are added together (essentially finding the average of mpgTankful). I tried implementing a counter but It's not turning out how I'd like it to. It should keep counting until a user enters -1 to quit.

A sample result would be:

Miles user entered:
Gallons user entered:
mpgTankful:
mpgTotal: (in this case mpgTankful would be divided by 1)

Miles user entered:
Gallons user entered:
mpgTankful:
mpgTotal: (in this case add previous mpgTankful with current mpgTankful and divide by 2)

Miles user entered:
Gallons user entered:
mpgTankful:
mpgTotal: (in this case add first mpgTankful with second and current (third) mpgTankful and divide by 3)

```
var miles,      //Miles driven
    gallons,    //Gallons used
    mpgTankful, //MPG this tankful
    mpgTotal,   //Total MPG 
    mi,         //Miles driven converted to integer
    gal,        //Gallons used converted to integer
    count=0,
    avg;

//Enter -1 to quit
while(miles!="-1"){

//Read in the Miles Driven from user as a String
miles=window.prompt("Enter miles (-1 to quit):");
    if(miles=="-1"){
        break;
    }

//Read in the Gallons used from user as a String
gallons=window.prompt("Enter gallons:");

//Convert numbers from Strings to Integers
mi=parseInt(miles);
gal=parseInt(gallons);

//Calculate the MPG Tankful
mpgTankful=mi/gal;

//Calculate the Total MPG
mpgTotal+=mpgTankful;
count++;

if(count!=0){
    avg=mpgTotal/count;
}
else
    avg=0;

document.writeln("avg: " + avg);

//Print Results
document.writeln("<br/><br/>Miles driven: " + mi +
                 "<br/>Gallons used: " + gal +
                 "<br/>MPG this tankful: " + mpgTankful +
                 "<br/>Total MPG: " + mpgTotal);

}
```

Comment: Would you mind placing some values in your sample? So we know the expected input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there...

`mpgTotal+=mpgTankful;`  can't work: the first time this is called, `mpgTotal === undefined`

The `if(count!=0)` is useless.. you incremented count one line above...

You calculated `avg` but didn't output it (according to the description for 'Total MPG: '): `<br/>Total MPG: " + mpgTotal`

For this example I added a looping check for invalid input (explanations in comments).

```html
<script>
var    miles=0  //Miles driven
,    gallons=0  //Gallons used
, mpgTankful=0  //MPG this tankful
,   mpgTotal=0  //Total MPG 
,         mi=0  //Miles driven converted to integer
,        gal=0  //Gallons used converted to integer
,      count=0
,        avg=0
; // end vars

main: while(true){  //main loop, labeled 'main'
  if( (miles=prompt('Enter miles ("-1" to quit):')) === '-1' )
    break main;     //well.. plain english..
  if( isNaN(mi=parseInt(miles, 10)) ){  //check if we get a number
    alert('Please enter a number or enter "-1" to quit.');
    continue main;
  }
  while(true){
    if( (gallons=prompt('Enter gallons ("-1" to quit):')) === '-1' )
      break main; //NOT this inner loop.
    if( isNaN(gal=parseInt(gallons, 10)) ){  //check if we got a number
      alert('Please enter a number or enter "-1" to quit.');
      //no need to instruct a continue for this loop..
    } else break; //this inner loop (so we can go on with 'main' below).
  }
  
  mpgTankful=mi/gal;     //Calculate the MPG Tankful
  
  mpgTotal+=mpgTankful;  //Calculate the Total MPG
  
  avg=mpgTotal/++count;  //Calculate avg (and pre-increment count)
  
  //Print Results
  document.writeln( '<br/><br/>Miles driven: ' + mi
                  + '<br/>Gallons used: '      + gal
                  + '<br/>MPG this tankful: '  + mpgTankful
                  + '<br/>Total MPG: '         + avg
                  );
}
document.close(); //don't forget to close the body..
</script>
```

This should get you started.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to have the user enter "-1" to exit the loop. I tried replacing the cancel with "-1" and keeping the if(miles=="-1"){break;} as I originally had, but it didn't work properly.

Comment: Here you go, done refactoring. Note, that not using cancel (as in my previous example) is rather *counter-intuitive*..

Comment: Update: switched `Number` to `parseInt` (because that's what you used and you specified integers). However, I'd recommend accepting floating point gallons (and miles), giving you significant better accuracy.